# Swift extend UIView to return calling type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uikit

I want to extend base class (UIView) where I work on that object and return the calling object with correct type

```swift
extension UIView {
    func withCleanBg() -> UIView {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        return self;
    }
}
```

For example if I call `let btn:UIButton = UIButton().withCleanBg()` I want the `btn` to stay UIButton after calling the extension and not to get UpCasted.

I want this to chain function calls like
`UIButton().withCleanBg().withFillInParent()` and so on

Comment: Not related to your question but you should use a computed property instead of e function considering that there is no parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `Self` as the type:

```
func withCleanBg() -> Self {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `Self` and use `@discardableResult` attribute so no need to care about the return. For more about [@discardableResult](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/discardableresult/)

```
extension UIView {
    @discardableResult
    func withCleanBg() -> Self {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        return self
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func withThemeCorner() -> Self {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return self
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func withFillInParent() -> Self {
        // Do your code here
        return self
    }
}
```

Example:

```
UIButton().withCleanBg().withFillInParent() // Now this will not give warning like "Result of call to 'withFillInParent()' is unused"
```